# php can not select database that created by user or phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database

I creat a database in cpanel and write small php code.

```
<?php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbuser='-------';
$dbpass='*******';
$db = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$db);
if(!$db){
    echo 'can not connect to server';
}
else{
    $database = '--------_ps';
    $select = mysql_select_db($database);
    if($select){
        echo 'database selected. <br/>';
    }
    else{
        echo 'database not select. <br/>';
    }
        mysql_close($db);
}
?>
```

I see database not select, When I change --------_ps database to phpmyadmin data base 'Database operations
information_schema' echo database selected.
I am not beginner on php but I don't know any way to solve this.
Please help me.

Comment: Try `$select = mysql_select_db($database,$db);`

Comment: you should start using mysqli instead of the mysql extension. The mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Check http://php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code -witch also provides some basic feedback as to what errors your script may encounter:

```
<?php
...
$conn = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect to the Database Server");  
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $conn );
mysql_select_db($database, $conn) or die("Could not find the Database");
...
?>
```

Now, the above script works. If you still encounter problems, can you please give some feedback with the error log of your web server?

One more thing: Make sure you have created the database correctly with the phpMyAdmin, AND also have set the user with the credentials you are using...

Comment: Tank you very much, the problem was "credential" of user.

Comment: @user3087175 glad to have helped! Happy holidays!